# Android App development uses of SHA1 key

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, sha1

I have created version 1 for my android application, and I started the new project as version 2 for my android application. And I have created the SHA1 key for my version 1 application, so am I need to create new SHA1 Key for my version 2? or can I use the same JSON service file which I used for version 1 android application.

Comment: It is not required to create new SHA1 key every time. Re-use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing any functionality or adding or removing any feature then only you have to use the new, otherwise simply reuse it

Comment: Yes I am adding new functionalities to the next version, so am i need to create new SHA1 Key for it and am i need to update new jsonservice regarding it.